# How do I set a python datetime to something that is (somewhat) relative to now?

Tags: python, datetime

I can do some basic time calcs in python such as these:

```
when = 'Mon Sep 08 00:00:00 +0000 2014'
frmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"

then = datetime.datetime.strptime(when,frmt)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = now-then
print delta
```

That will calculate how much time has elapsed since *when*.

What I want to do is to set *when* to a very specific time. And that time will depend on what today is. I want *when* to be midnight (zero hours) of the immediately previous Monday from today. **How can I do that?**

Comment: [`timedelta` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and the [`datetime.replace` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) are your friends here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 12, 40, 25, 525000)
>>> when = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> when
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 0, 0)
>>> when.weekday()
2
>>> when = when - datetime.timedelta(when.weekday())
>>> when
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 8, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.now()
days_from_monday = today.weekday()
if days_from_monday == 0:
    days_from_monday = 7
monday = today + timedelta(days=-days_from_monday)
midnight_monday = monday.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

`datetime.replace` can be used to easily change parts of a datetime, but note that datetimes are immutable and that `.replace` returns a new one.

`datetime.weekday` will give you the day of the week. Monday=0 to Saturday=6